# “Please run ‘e2fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p7’ first” when trying to resize partition using GParted

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I’m running GParted from a live usb. When GParted tries to execute `resize2fs -p /dev/nvme0n1p7` It throws an error and says “Please run ‘e2fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p7’ first”.

I have tried running the above command in terminal and following it with `resize2fs -p /dev/nvme0n1p7` but get the same error. I’ve also tried rebooting as well as running `chkdsk /f` on windows.

Not sure what else to try. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi. Not sure it will help but Keep in mind that you cannot  fsck on a mounted drive. Are you doing it on an unmounted drive?

Comment: Yes, the drive is unmounted.

Comment: e2fsck only works on the extX family of formats. And chkdsk only works on Windows formats. What format is partition?

Comment: ext4. I gave up and came back the next morning and it worked, no restart or anything. I love computers.

Answer (score 6):

It has to do with the timezone of your system. GParted live, for instance, boots with UTC timezone.

If you are in GMT+something timezone, then the last time the partition was mounted is in the future. Therefore, running `e2fsck` does not update the date that `resize2fs` is checking to insure that the partition was checked.

Setting a date in the future, or waiting for a day, will be sufficient to resolve this issue.

I had the same problem as you, and your update gave me the idea to try that.

Comment: You're exactly right.  However Instead of resetting the date on your system, you could just mount and unmount the drive. That will reset the last mount time to whatever your current system time is.

Comment: this comment about mounting and unmounting is genius, worked for me. Here's a good guide of how to mount and unmount from CLI: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029040/how-to-manually-mount-a-partition

Answer (score 2):

In my case any change in the RTC or system date and time changed nothing and I kept getting the same error over and over again.

The solution was to add the -f option to resize2fs, e.g.

resize2fs -fp /dev/sda1 100M